# How can set ListView's scope as before

Tags: android, listview

I use below code to show the same scope of ListView:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
FirstPosition = this.getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition();
//call B activity
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
this.getListView().setSelection(FirstPosition);
//.....
}
```

I want to let the ListView show the same scope before call B activity and resume after B activity.
But my method may have some offset.
How can I do to above it?